# how to find index of match between two set of data frame

Tags: r

Two data frame with one being my reference

```
df1<- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(2L, 14L, 8L, 12L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 
5L, 6L, 9L, 10L, 16L, 7L, 15L, 11L, 13L), .Label = c("A", "AbC", 
"B", "C", "D", "F", "FFFS", "G6_7", "GI666", "GTJJJ", "HINDO", 
"MirTn", "Mumbai", "NdFi1", "TRS100", "TTTNKK"), class = "factor"), 
    V2 = c(10L, 22L, 33L, 35L, 89L, 6L, 973L, 686L, 82L, 22L, 
    1L, 82L, 1L, 9304L, 43L, 736L)), .Names = c("V1", "V2"), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-16L))


df2<- structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 4L, 5L, 3L, 2L, 6L), .Label = c("AbC", 
"Bangalore", "Dehli", "F", "GI666", "Mumbai"), class = "factor")), .Names = "V1", class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-6L))
```

I want to find the index of those that match and a dash for those that are not match between df1$V1 and df2$V1

I tried to do it with no success, it is because the R is repeating the index over the column

```
df1$myindex <- as.character(which(df1$V1 %in% df2$V1))
```

what I am looking for is shown below

```
#         V1 myindex 
#1       AbC    1
#2         F    9
#3     GI666    10
#4     Dehli    -
#5 Bangalore    -
#6    Mumbai    16
```

Comment: @akrun I saw the post you suggested , the problem is that one of my data frame is smaller than the other one and that is why it is not applicable. On the other hand, I believe there should be a much simpler way to do it than it is shown in that post

Comment: This I believe is a common problem using `match`.  If you don't think it is a dupe, I can reopen it.

Comment: @akrun I dont think it is a duplicated question. if you have a solution , I would be more than happy to accept it because I could not solve it based on the search in here I did

Comment: You already got a solution below, but I think it is better to leave it as NA instead of `-` as this converts to `character` class unnecessarily

Comment: @akrun sure, so you mean it is better to use `match`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38976959/trying-to-apply-a-classification-in-one-dataframe-to-a-variable-in-another-data/38977162#38977162)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `match`

```
match(df2$V1, df1$V1)
#[1]  1  9 10 NA NA 16
```

If you do not want `NA` and want it as `-`, you can use `ifelse`

```
i1 <- match(df2$V1, df1$V1)
df2$myindex <- ifelse(is.na(i1), "-", i1)
df2
#         V1 myindex
#1       AbC       1
#2         F       9
#3     GI666      10
#4     Dehli       -
#5 Bangalore       -
#6    Mumbai      16
```

Comment: I want the output I showed, otherwise it gives me which(df1$V1 %in% df2$V1) what you just wrote