# Trying to apply a classification in one dataframe, to a variable in another dataframe

Tags: r

despite the complicated title, what i want to do is simple:

If I have two dataframes:

```
d <- data.frame(V1 = c("a","b","c","d"), V2 = c("P", "M", "M", "P"))
j <- data.frame(V3 = c("d","b","b","c","d","c", "a"))
```

and I want to insert another column into dataframe j, called V4 which assigns the same classification in d i.e. the final dataframe will look like:

```
j

V3 V4
d   P
b   M
b   M
c   M 
d   P
c   M
a   P
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use `match`

```
j$V4 <- d$V2[match(j$V3, d$V1)]

j
#   V3 V4
#1  d  P
#2  b  M
#3  b  M
#4  c  M
#5  d  P
#6  c  M
#7  a  P
```